# How to set python click parameter to alias different parameter from option callback?

Tags: python-3.x, python-click

There are many utilities that have one option to be an alias for others, like the following:

```
$ python3 ./1.py --help
Usage: 1.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --format TEXT
  --long TEXT    Alias to --format=long_format
  --help         Show this message and exit.
```

How would I implement `--long` option in click so that click automatically sets `--long=long_format` when the option is used in an easy matter?

I ended up using a global variable to override locally the arguments:

```
import argparse
from typing import Any, Optional

import click

PARAMS = {}


def set_param(
    opt: str, val: Any, ctx: click.Context, param: Optional[click.Parameter], value: Any
):
    if value:
        PARAMS[opt] = val


@click.command()
@click.option("--format", default="default_format")
@click.option(
    "--long",
    is_flag=True,
    help="Alias to --format=long_format",
    callback=lambda *args: set_param("format", "long_format", *args),
)
def cli(**kwargs):
    args = argparse.Namespace(**{**kwargs, **PARAMS})
    print(args.format)


cli()
```

But inside `@click.option(callback=<here>)` there is already `ctx` available. I tried setting `ctx.params["format"] = "long_format"`, but it does not work. Is there a better way to set @click.option alias automatically set different option? I tried reading click source code and documentation, but did not find anything relevant.

In other words, how to implement the following @click.option callback:

```
import argparse
from typing import Any, Optional
import click    

@click.command()
@click.option("--format", default="default_format")
@click.option(
    "--long",
    is_flag=True,
    help="Alias to --format=long_format",
    callback=lambda *args: "How to set --format=long_format from here?",
)
def cli(**kwargs):
    args = argparse.Namespace(**{**kwargs, **PARAMS})
    print(args.format)


cli()
```

---

Based on the amazing answer below, I created this:

```
def __alias_option_callback(
    aliased: Dict[str, Any],
    ctx: click.Context,
    param: click.Parameter,
    value: Any,
):
    """Callback called from alias_option option."""
    if value:
        for paramname, val in aliased.items():
            param = next(p for p in ctx.command.params if p.name == paramname)
            param.default = val

def alias_option(
    *param_decls: str,
    aliased: Dict[str, Any],
    **attrs: Any,
):
    """Add this to click options to have an alias for other options"""
    aliasedhelp = " ".join(
        "--"
        + k.replace("_", "-")
        + ("" if v is True else f"={v}" if isinstance(v, int) else f"={v!r}")
        for k, v in aliased.items()
    )
    return click.option(
        *param_decls,
        is_flag=True,
        help=f"Alias to {aliasedhelp}",
        callback=lambda *args: __alias_option_callback(aliased, *args),
        **attrs,
    )

@click.command()
# Auto generates help= and sets --format when used.
@alias_option("--long", aliased=dict(format="long_format"))
def cli():
   pass
```

It's not perfect, as it does not handle `False` properly, but works for my limited use case.

Comment: Are you using `@click.pass_context`?

Comment: Hi, I do not understand. No, in the example given I do not use `@click.pass_context`. Note that _some_ context is passed to `@click.option(callback=lambda ctx <here>)`, but I do no see how it can influence the context further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can set the default value of the `--format` option programatically:

```py
import argparse
from typing import Any, Optional

import click


def set_long(ctx, *_):
    for p in ctx.command.params:
        if p.name == "format":
            p.default = "long_format"


@click.command()
@click.option("--format", default="default_format")
@click.option(
    "--long", is_flag=True, help="Alias to --format=long_format", callback=set_long
)
def cli(**kwargs):
    args = argparse.Namespace(**kwargs)
    print(args.format)


cli()
```

Invoking `python3 script.py --long` will print:

```
long_format
```